# Formatting Date

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am on MVC.

In my model i got a variable `Datetime`

In my view I am trying to give this a format when the page loads.

Control

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.RequestedLaunchDate, new { @class = "dateselector", @style = "float:left;" })
```

my JS is like

```
            var now = new Date();//Today's date
            now.format("dd/MM/yyyy");
            $(".dateselector").datepicker("setDate", now);
```

But still when the page loads i get the display as

```
18/03/2014 00:00:00
```

Why ?

What did I do wrong ?

Comment: Where is `format` defined?

Comment: now.format("dd/MM/yyyy"); -> TypeError: Object [object Date] has no method 'format'. I'd recommend using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

Comment: and if `format` does exits, I'd expect it to return a new value, not mutate the original date.

Comment: Have you considered changing the type of `RequestedLaunchDate` to `string`, and formatting it server-side?

Comment: What is wrong is that you are feeding a string to your datepicker while it expects a date. Set the formatting on the datepicker like Emil H's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Date` in javascript has no `format` method defined (by default). What you probably want is to pass the formatting to jQuery UI datepicker as documented [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat). Something along the lines of:

```
var now = new Date();//Today's date
$(".dateselector").datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "dd/MM/yyyy" );
$(".dateselector").datepicker("setDate", now);
```

This will set change how the datepicker formats your date. If you add it somewhere else on your page you can use:

```
var dateString = $.datepicker.formatDate( "dd/MM/yyyy", date );
```

This will give you a string representation of the date formatted as you wish.

Another, more robust way, would be to set the locale you want:

```
var locale = 'de'; // Use the locale you want.
$.datepicker.setDefaults( $.datepicker.regional[ locale ] );
```

Setting this will localize your datepicker along with the date format displayed in it.

Answer (score 0):

`Date` object in JavaScript has no `format` method by default. You might use some plugin such as [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

However, you can do that without any JavaScript, but using the following data annotation on server side:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
```

Put this line of code to right above the `RequestedLaunchDate` property of your `Model`

Or you can refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript?rq=1) for more options about formatting date with JavaScript.

Comment: I downvoted because he is using a datepicker and the datepicker should be responsible for displaying the correct format.

Answer (score 0):

```
  var now = new Date();//Today's date 
  $(".dateselector").datepicker("setDate", now);
```

Solved my problem.

Comment: Emil H. has said the same thing, only more elaborate, hasn't he?

Answer (score 0):

```
var now = new Date();//Today's date
var day = now.getDate();
var month = now.getMonth()+1;
var year = now.getFullYear();
if (month < 10) { month = '0' + month; }
var newDate=(day + '/' + month + '/' + year); // This will give "dd/mm/yyyy"

$(".dateselector").datepicker("setDate", newDate);
```

Answer (score -1):

please try to this solution to formate date.

It will help you:

```
var format_date = function(date){
    return  ("0"+date).slice(-2)
}
var format_month = function(month){
   return  ("0"+month).slice(-2)
}
var now = new Date();

formate_complete_date = format_date(now.getDate())+"/"+format_month(now.getMonth())+"/"+now.getFullYear() +" "+now.getHours()+":"+now.getMinutes()+":"+now.getSeconds();

console.log(formate_complete_date)
```